# LiveCode IDE utility needs to complete task uninterrupted

Tags: ide, livecode

A utility plugin running in the LiveCode IDE needs to complete a database update task every so often.  It's important that the task isn't interrupted by the user - who may be working on another stack.  Is there a way to disable the standard ctrl + period and avoid the task being stopped half way through it's cycle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the global 'allowInterrupts' property for this:

```
  set the allowInterrupts to false
  ... task you don't want interrupted ...
  set the allowInterrupts to true
```

While this property is false, Ctrl-Period will have no effect.